# QSet not letting me add my own types

Tags: qt, hash, set

I'm using QT and I have a QSet I wish to add `vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>` to.  My syntax is `QSet<vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> >`.  However, I'm getting the following compilation error.

```
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\..\..\src\corelib\tools\qhash.h:880: error: C2665: 'qHash' : none of the 16 overloads could convert all the argument types
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(62): could be 'uint qHash(char)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(63): or       'uint qHash(uchar)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(64): or       'uint qHash(signed char)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(65): or       'uint qHash(ushort)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(66): or       'uint qHash(short)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(67): or       'uint qHash(uint)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(68): or       'uint qHash(int)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(69): or       'uint qHash(ulong)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(77): or       'uint qHash(long)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(78): or       'uint qHash(quint64)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(86): or       'uint qHash(qint64)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(87): or       'uint qHash(QChar)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(88): or       'uint qHash(const QByteArray &)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(89): or       'uint qHash(const QString &)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(90): or       'uint qHash(const QStringRef &)'
c:\qt\4.7.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qhash.h(91): or       'uint qHash(const QBitArray &)'
```

while trying to match the argument list '(const vtkSmartPointer)'
with

```
[
    T=vtkImageData
]
```

To me this looks like I have to write my own hashing function

1. Is this correct?
2. If so how do I do this?
3. If not what is going on?

I am a newbie to QT coming over from Java where I never had to worry about writing my own hash function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that you have to write your own hashing function for the `vtkSmartPointer` class because Qt does not provide one. Qt does however provide a hash function for pointers (`qHash(const T *)`) so you could try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
uint qHash(const vtkSmartPointer<T> &p)
{
    return qHash(p.GetPointer());
}
```

Comment: Where would this go?  Would this guarantee that two pointers that point to different data would return different hashing functions?

Comment: You would need to have this definition available when you declare your `QSet<vtkSmartPointer<T> >`. So you could put it in the same source file that you use the `QSet` in or in a header file if you need to use it from multiple source files. This function just uses Qt's qHash() function which calculates the hash based on the value of the pointer. Qt is a mature and well tested library so I'm sure that their hashing functions work.